# Parsing data from JSON API in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, pandas

I made a little program to parse data from an API.
I do not have experience with Pandas. It is working but I would like to know how to do that better and more efficiently.

````
class Albion_data():
    def __init__(self,item):
        self.location = f'Bridgewatch,Thetford,FortSterling,Martlock,Bridgewatch,Lymhurst'
        self.item = item
    @property
    def get_data(self):
        url = f"https://www.albion-online-data.com/api/v1/stats/Prices/{self.item}?locations={self.location}"
        response = (requests.get(url).text)
        response_json = json.loads(response)
        if response_json != []:
            response_json = pd.DataFrame(response_json)[["item_id", "city", "sell_price_min"]]
            max = response_json.loc[response_json["sell_price_min"].idxmax()]
            min = response_json.loc[response_json["sell_price_min"].idxmin()]
            gain = max[2] - min[2]
            data = pd.DataFrame(
                [[max[0], max[1], min[1], min[2], max[2], gain]],
                columns=["ITEM", "CITY max ", "CITY min", "MIN_PRICE", "MAX PRICE", "GAIN"])

            return data

def get_data_frame():
    item_list = pd.read_csv('items.txt', sep=':', names=['nuber', 'item']['item']
    item_price = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ITEM", "CITY max ", "CITY min","MIN_PRICE", "MAX PRICE", "GAIN"])
    for item in item_list:
        item_price = item_price.append(Albion_data(item).get_data)
        item_price.to_csv('data.csv')
    return item_price
```
````

Comment: Is `get_data_frame` an instance method, a class method, or not associated with the class?

Comment: This is not associated with the class but the wrong indentation.

Answer (score 3):

### Do you need a class?

Right now, I'm not sure you need a class. Your class has two methods, one of which is `__init__`, so this could be refactored to be a function

```py
def get_data(item):
    location = f'Bridgewatch,Thetford,FortSterling,Martlock,Bridgewatch,Lymhurst'
    url = f"https://www.albion-online-data.com/api/v1/stats/Prices/{item}?locations={location}"
    # you also don't need these parentheses
    response = requests.get(url).text
    response_json = json.loads(response)
    if response_json != []:
        response_json = pd.DataFrame(response_json)[["item_id", "city", "sell_price_min"]]
        max = response_json.loc[response_json["sell_price_min"].idxmax()]
        min = response_json.loc[response_json["sell_price_min"].idxmin()]
        gain = max[2] - min[2]
        data = pd.DataFrame(
                [[max[0], max[1], min[1], min[2], max[2], gain]],
                columns=["ITEM", "CITY max ", "CITY min", "MIN_PRICE", "MAX PRICE", "GAIN"])

        return data
```

This minimizes the cost of constructing the class just to get a dataframe.

### Checking the Value of `json.loads`

Now, I'm not completely sure what `response.text` will look like every time, but reading your code, it will *always* be a `list`. The fact that there's no `else` means that if your code doesn't satisfy the `if` statement, it will return `None`, which could lead to `TypeErrors` in your dataframe construction. It might be easier to make a generator, that way you can easily skip return values:

```py
# set the argument to be an iterable

def get_data(items):
    columns=["ITEM", "CITY max ", "CITY min", "MIN_PRICE", "MAX PRICE", "GAIN"])
    location = f'Bridgewatch,Thetford,FortSterling,Martlock,Bridgewatch,Lymhurst'

    for item in items:
        url = f"https://www.albion-online-data.com/api/v1/stats/Prices/{item}?locations={location}"
        response = requests.get(url).text
        response_json = json.loads(response)

        # rely on the falsiness of empty lists and enforce that it will indeed be
        # a list type using isinstance
        if response_json and isinstance(response_json, list):
            # since response_json is a list, don't create a dataframe,
            # you can instead provide a key to the max and min functions
            maxval = max(response_json, key=lambda x: x['sell_price_min'])
            minval = min(response_json, key=lambda x: x['sell_price_min'])

            # Now you don't need to rely on an index
            gain = maxval['sell_price_min'] - minval['sell_price_min']
            vals = [maxval.pop('item_id')]
            for k in ('city','sell_price_min'):
                vals.append(maxval[k])
                vals.append(minval[k])
            vals.append(gain)
            yield dict(zip(vals, columns))
```

Now, in case the `if` statement isn't `True`, you won't get `None` from the function:

```py
def func(a):
   if a<2:
       return [1,2]

df = pd.DataFrame([func(x) for x in range(4)], columns = ['a', 'b'])
# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

The benefit here is that now your `get_data_frame` function can be a lot easier to leverage:

```py
def get_data_frame():
    item_list = pd.read_csv('items.txt', sep=':', names=['nuber', 'item']['item']

    # You also don't need to initialize the item_price dataframe

    # You can use a list comprehension, and because your items are
    # dictionaries, you don't need to specify the columns
    item_price = pd.DataFrame([a for a in get_data(item_list)])
    item_price.to_csv('data.csv')
    return item_price
```

### read_csv

Now, the only other issue I can see is that you are collecting everything into memory multiple times with `pd.read_csv`. You really only want the item_id's, so just iterate over a file handle directly:

```py
def file_iterate():
    with open('items.txt') as fh:
        for line in fh:
            # item is the second entry, so split on ':' and grab index 1
            yield line.split(':')[1].strip()

def get_data_frame():
    items = file_iterate()
    item_price = pd.DataFrame([a for a in get_data(items)])
    item_price.to_csv('data.csv')
    return item_price
```

The generators will allow you to keep one dataframe in-memory, and produces values one at a time.

### try/except

The last thing I'd do is to ensure the program doesn't crash on a bad web request or attempt at `json.loads`:

```py
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

def get_data(items):
    columns=["ITEM", "CITY max ", "CITY min", "MIN_PRICE", "MAX PRICE", "GAIN"])
    location = f'Bridgewatch,Thetford,FortSterling,Martlock,Bridgewatch,Lymhurst'

    for item in items:
        url = f"https://www.albion-online-data.com/api/v1/stats/Prices/{item}?locations={location}"
        # wrap in try/except here
        try:
            response = requests.get(url).text
            response_json = json.loads(response)
        except JSONDecodeError as e:
            print(f'bad json for {item}')
            continue # skip it so it doesn't ruin your process, or you can raise it
        except HTTPError as e:
            print(f'HTTPError on {url}'
            continue # skip or you can raise
        except Exception: # Unexpected error
            raise
        # rest of function
```

Comment: Your solution has a little mistake. Max_price is the wrong value. I corrected that:           for k in ['city','sell_price_min']:
                vals.append(maxval[k])
                vals.append(minval[k])

Comment: @Dawid I'll make that edit in my answer, I was leaning on the ordered-ness of python3.6+ dictionaries

Comment: @Dawid you'll want to use `for k in ('city', 'sell_price_min')` since the tuple is smaller in size